# Value Acceso of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: php, android, json, webservice

Tengo un problema con mi Web Service, estoy intentando obtener mis valores que están guardados en una base de datos, pero cuando consulto el web services desde el explorador me da la información correcta lo cual me hace pensar que el WbService ya funciona, el problema es que ahora quiero consultarlo desde una aplicacion android pero me da este error:

> Value Acceso of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to
>   JSONObject

No entiendo este error, mi Web Serivice esta de esta forma:

```
<?PHP
require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );

$hostname_localhost = "localhost";
$database_localhost = "prueba";
$username_localhost = "root";
$password_localhost = "";

$json=array();

    if(isset($_GET["name_usu"])){
        $nombre_usuario = $_GET["name_usu"];
        $password = $_GET["password"];

        include 'PasswordHash.php';

        echo $pass;

        $conexion = mysqli_connect($hostname_localhost, $username_localhost, $password_localhost, $database_localhost);
        mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");
        $consulta="SELECT ID, user, pass, nickname, email, url, fecha_registro, name_mostrar FROM usuarios WHERE user = '{$name_usu}'";
        $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

        if($registro=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){



        $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, true);   // 16 digit hashing password
        $pass = $wp_hasher->HashPassword($_POST['password']); //$posted['password'] is your password

        if($wp_hasher->CheckPassword( $password, $registro[2] )){
            echo "Acceso correcto";
            //Si todo funciona mandaremos la informacion a este array
            $json['sesion'][]=$registro;

        }else{
            echo "El usuario es incorrecto";
        }

        }else{
            $resultar["ID"]='No registrado';
            $resultar["user"]='No registrado';
            $resultar["pass"]='No registrado';
            $resultar["nickname"]='No registrado';
            $resultar["email"]='No registrado';
            $resultar["url"]='No registrado';
            $resultar["fecha_registro"]='No registrado';
            $resultar["name_mostrar"]='No registrado';
            $json['sesion'][]=$resultar;
        }

        mysqli_close($conexion);
        echo json_encode($json);

    }else{
        $resultar["success"]=0;
        $resultar["message"]='Ws no Retorna';
        $json['sesion'][]=$resultar;
        echo json_encode($json);
    }
?>
```

> Acceso
>   correcto{"sesion":[{"0":"1757","ID":"1757","1":"bdprueba","user":"bdprueba","2":"$P$BhbEVMLV6onULEfYLG3dsF5xuv9t9j0","pass":"$P$BhbEVMLV6onULEfYLG3dsF5xuv9t9j0","3":"bdprueba","nickname":"bdprueba","4":"pruebadb@outlook.com","email":"pruebadb@outlook.com","5":"","url":"","6":"2019-02-20
>   15:35:53","fecha_registro":"2019-02-20 15:35:53","7":"enrique
>   espinosa","nombre_mostrar":"enrique espinosa"}]}

Y en mi aplicacion tengo esto en el metodo OnResponde y en el onErrorResponse:

```
@Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

        JSONArray json = response.optJSONArray("sesion");
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;

        try{
            jsonObject = json.getJSONObject(0);
            ID = (jsonObject.getInt("ID"));
            user = (jsonObject.getString("user"));
            pass = (jsonObject.getString("pass"));
            //claveBD = (jsonObject.getString("clave"));
            nickname = (jsonObject.getString("nickname"));
            email = (jsonObject.getString("email"));
            url = (jsonObject.getString("url"));
            fecha_Registro = (jsonObject.getDouble("fecha_registro"));
            nombre_mostrar = (jsonObject.getString("nombre_mostrar"));
            //(jsonObject.getString("recordado"));

        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (nombreBD.equals("No registrado") || passwordBD.equals("No registrado")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Los datos son incorrectos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else if(passwordBD.equals(passwordCaja)){

            registrarUsuario(nombreBD, passwordBD,"master",rolBD, empresaBD, box);

        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "La contraseña es incorrecta", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error al conectar al servidor: "+error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("servidor","Error de conexion: "+error);
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Android espera un JSON, por lo tanto no puedes sacar por pantalla cosas como `echo "Acceso correcto";` ni nada de nada, **solamente un JSON**, porque cualquier cosa que salga por pantalla, aun sea un espacio en blanco, ya lo fastidia todo. Es lo que pasa de hecho, mira aquí: **`Acceso correcto{"sesion":[{"0":"1757","ID,`** Ahí está, lo que sacaste con el `echo` fastidiándolo todo. ¿Espera un JSON?, no saques nada que no sea un JSON. ¿Quieres emitir ciertos mensajes de error?  Ningún problema, pero debes hacerlo en forma de JSON, creando un array por ejemplo y mandándolo con `json_encode`.

Comment: Tienes razón, no sabia que eso me afectaba, pero ya me devolvió otro error diferente, pero el error de esta pregunta quedo cubierto, muchas gracias.

Comment: Pues sí afecta, con que hagas `echo " ";` si la App espera un JSON, eso daña el JSON, porque pone eso antes o después. En eso hay que ser muy estricto. El otro error que te da es quizá porque estás leyendo mal ciertos valores. Por ejemplo haces algo como `ID = (jsonObject.getInt("ID"));` pero si observas el JSON, **en `ID` no hay un entero, es una cadena, porque el valor está entre comillas: `"1757"`** por tanto debes usar `getString` y la variable debe ser declarada como `String` en Android. O puedes modificar el JSON, para que sea reconocido como entero debe estar así: `"ID":1757`

Comment: De echo era porque estaba llamando a una variable que no existe por eso no me marcaba un error como nulo.

Comment: Podrias poner tu respuesta para marcarla como correcta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código no es coherente en varios puntos, los cuales paso a enumerar:

1. Si la app espera un JSON, en el código PHP no debe salir por pantalla **en ningún momento ninguna otra cosa que no sea un JSON**. De hecho si observas el resultado: `Acceso correcto{"sesion":[{"0":"1757","ID":"1757","1":"bdprueba","user":"b ...` el `echo` que haces fuera del JSON está fastidiando todo. Por tanto, quita esos `echo`.
2. La lectura que haces del JSON en Android tampoco es coherente. Por ejemplo, intentas buscar un entero aquí: `ID = (jsonObject.getInt("ID"));` pero en el JSON ese valor no será reconocido como entero, porque está entre comillas: `"ID":"1757"`, para que sea reconocido como entero, tiene que estar así en el JSON: `"ID":1757` No puedes intentar sacar como entero ningún valor que esté entre comillas, eso dará error.
3. En la lectura Android del JSON no hay coherencia para los casos erróneos. Los cuales tampoco son manejados con claridad en PHP. Yo haría para los casos erróneos simplemente una array así: `$arr=array ("error"=>"Mensaje de error");` y luego en Android lo primero que haría sería buscar si el JSON tiene una clave `error` para mostrarlo y si no la tiene es que todo está OK y paso a sacar lo que hay en `sesion`. Este tipo de peticiones tienen que ser coherentes de un lado y de otro y manejarlas de una forma diáfana, de lo contrario la App hará crash ante una situación que no has sabido contemplar como programador.

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudarme y saber que estoy haciendo mal :)